# Source For Ahavat Chinam; Unwaranted Love

Tags: sources-mekorot, love

I have often heard the term *Ahavat Chinam* unwarranted love referenced as the antidote to *sinat chinam* unwarranted hate. What are the earliest sources for this (first) expression, particularly in the above context of solving unwarranted hate. The earliest I found was [this](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_38348_118.pdf#xml=http://www.hebrewbooks.org/hilite.aspx?pgnum=118&hilite=65fc7be7-ed7c-4157-ad53-0232dc4a6e65&toolbar=1&navpanes=0&statusbar=0&view=FitH) from 1930.

---

Hint: I have heard this idea ascribed to R. Kook z"l, so that might be a good place to look.

Comment: Please see my updated answer - I've taken this as far as I can go. It's probably the Pele Yoetz quoting either a lost sefer or something akin to folk wisdom.

Comment: And I just ran in a circle trying to trace down an acronym that ended up being the sefer Oros HaKodesh from R'Kook... More info here: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%94%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%9D

Comment: My Rebbe, based on a few Rishonim's explanation of sinas chinam, has said that the tikun for sinas chinam is not ahavas chinam, it's sina ke'halacha and ahava ke'halacha (not discounting idea's of lifnim mi'shuras ha'din). I am always shocked at big Rabbi's discussing ahavas chinam as this does not seem to be a Torah idea or ideal. Who we love and hate is supposed to be dictated by the Torah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know only the term `שנאת חנם` appears in this context until Rav Kook wrote:

> אם נחרבנו, ונחרב העולם עמנו על ידי שנאת חנם, נשוב להבנות והעולם עמנו יבנה, על ידי אהבת חנם" (אורות הקודש ג שכד).‏

Comment: You mean אהבת חנם?

Comment: No, before Rav Kook, שנאת חנם, then he wrote...

Comment: Your language is a bit confusing. Are you saying that only S'Ch as a phrase existed until Rav Kook coined the countering phrase Ahavas Chinam in Oros HaKodesh?

Comment: When was Oros written? was it pre-1930?

Comment: Written yes, published no.

Answer (score 5):

### UPDATE:

***Having finally traced down a searchable text of the [majority of the] Zohar, I can confidently say that it DOES NOT seem to reference the phrase "Ahavat Chinam" in Hebrew at all, and certainly not in contrast to "Sinat Chinam." [Though it may be in the few still-unavailable volumes in Devarim.] Thus, the earliest traceable reference to this issue is the Pele Yoetz's 1824 discussion of Ahavah being a tikkun for Sinas Chinam, in contrast to the Alshich's focus on eliminating jealousy as a cure of S"Ch. The Darash Moshe (1912 or earlier) seems to be the first to specifically refer to the concept of Ahavas Chinam.***

I've traced it to a [possuk in Yishayahu](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t1052.htm) (52:3) where the medrash seems derived from.
The [Pele Yo'etz references this](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%A5_%D7%A9) as well in "Sin'ah" and talks about Sinas Chinam and the tikkun of ahavah in general (and particularly for one's wife), pushing the [earliest mention to 1824](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pele_Yoetz), but he does not use the explicit phrase of Ahavas Chinam. ***He identifies the source vaguely as RaZa"L, indicating that this concept either stems from a well known specific source of multiple origins (possibly lost to us) or well known "folk knowledge" - that it was a popular concept in circulation without specific attribution.***

Oddly enough, the possuk in Yishayahu DOES come up in the gemara [in Sanhedrin 97b](http://www.yesmalot.co.il/torat-il/mamarim/mtei35.asp), but it's interpreted differently there. [This source](https://books.google.com/books?id=THFBAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=%D7%97%D6%B4%D7%A0%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%9D%20%D7%A0%D6%B4%D7%9E%D6%B0%D7%9B%D6%BC%D6%B7%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B6%D7%9D&source=bl&ots=venmw7-7vK&sig=8iXijKdES0j0ndjjtiVwzUkU7eg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBWoVChMIxN33s_D9xgIVQReSCh1TFgZI#v=onepage&q=%D7%97%D6%B4%D7%A0%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%9D%20%D7%A0%D6%B4%D7%9E%D6%B0%D7%9B%D6%BC%D6%B7%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B6%D7%9D&f=false) from 1895 apparently places it in Zohar on Va'Eschanan, though it provides a different page number (267).

Multiple sources in the late 1800's hone in on the Sinas Chinam aspect, which they attribute to the Alshich, but state that the source is primarly economic jealousy, so they avoid the "Ahavas Chinam" route.

Here's [another source](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38348&hilite=e294000b-892d-4c37-8a8e-687be3b25226&st=%22%25u05d0%25u05d4%25u05d1%3F%20%25u05d7%25u05e0%25u05dd%22) from the Imrei Fi in 1930 as well. That two sources (one in Poland and the other in Isreal, no less) in the same year use a similar term implies it was in use earlier.

Here's one from [Ma'agalei Tzedek](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33841&hilite=99858674-4dc3-458c-8f4c-e47f3ec20da4&st=%22%D7%90%D7%94%D7%91%3F%20%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%9D%22) (Munkatch) in 1884, but it's specifically in reference to Hashem rather than an antidote to Sinat Chinam.

Same with [this Haggadah](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=10894&hilite=5e02ceb4-24ab-41eb-bbde-2f6c1d2f6cfa&st=%22%D7%90%D7%94%D7%91%3F%20%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%9D%22) (Mareh Yechezkel) from 1894, whose [original printing](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=10790&hilite=f622c15d-66f9-4d40-a1b8-41548e6054b3&st=%22%D7%90%D7%94%D7%91%3F%20%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%9D%22) is from 1879.

The earliest source of the phrase I've found is 1838 from the [Mata'ei Moshe](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=23917&hilite=3de2f0d2-7ba1-4976-b1f9-cdc69bd4f3bb&st=%22%D7%90%D7%94%D7%91%3F%20%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%9D%22), but again, this is reference to Ahavas Hashem.

The [Darash Moshe](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24683&hilite=e72e5b3b-dc93-4a0d-b0d8-0360a35dedc5&st=%22%D7%90%D7%94%D7%91%3F%20%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%9D%22) in his Chidushei Aggados on Sanhedrin (in 1912, but since this is a compilation of sefarim it was probably written much earlier) brings down an interesting midrash that's related; "I sold them (Yisroel) for Free/Chinam" - because of Sinas Chinam, "And they will be redeemed for Free/Chinam" - that is when the Tzadikim love one another also freely.

I was able to trace this down to a Midrash Tanchumah in Devarim, but the exact text has to do with a discussion on Hashem "selling" Israel into golus, so it seems that the Darash Moshe is engaging in some form of poetic embellishment (possibly based upon the Pele Yoetz?), though he does reference the Zohar.

Comment: Where exactly in the Tanchuma are you refering to?

Comment: @user6591 Devarim on Netzavim (which isn't on wikisource yet), specifically it's in 8.7, but it looks like it's just a reference to Isaiah 52:3. Need sources on that possuk...

Comment: The closest to this sentiment I see there is at the end of ois Aleph. אין ישראל נגאלין עד שיהיו כלן אגודה אחת.

Comment: But in the Buber edition, the end of אות ז׳ as well as the standard version אות ג׳ has the words ואתם לא נמכרתם בדמים but that Is a completely different discussion. Klal Yisroel said they were relieved of their duty to keep the Torah after Hashem sold us up the river, just like a sold slave who cannot eat Trumah any longer, to which Yechezkel responded we were not sold with money so we are still in His possession.

Comment: So that would mean the rest of that line from the Darash Moshe was a poetic addition of lovely sentiment.

Comment: @user6591 see the edits to my answer - it's earlier than the Darash moshe now, might be an interpretation of the Pele Yo'etz, or may actually be in the Zohar, but I can't pin it down...

Comment: @user6591 I also found another sefer that references the same possuk in yishayahu as a reference to sinas chinam and the need for tikun of that sin in order to bring geula - Chomas Anach (1903) by Chayim Yosef Dovid Azulai.

Comment: @user6591 The Even Shoham in 1899 pins the drasha of Chinam=Sinas Chinam on the Alshich... So does the Bris Avraham. But they say the ultimate cause is jealousy. https://books.google.com/books?id=Rpw_AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42&dq=%D7%97%D6%B4%D7%A0%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%9D+%D7%A0%D6%B4%D7%9E%D6%B0%D7%9B%D6%BC%D6%B7%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B6%D7%9D&source=bl&ots=UG5UOZMkhN&sig=Ep0BedeBguxShfDqIp8ICKne9ng&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwATgKahUKEwjU8-W79v3GAhVFFj4KHflyDxk#v=onepage&q=%D7%97%D6%B4%D7%A0%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%9D%20%D7%A0%D6%B4%D7%9E%D6%B0%D7%9B%D6%BC%D6%B7%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B6%D7%9D&f=false

Comment: I really think youneed to start from scratch here. The source in your drasha you linked is Rav Kook. The same Rav Kook mentioned by the OP. The Pele Yoetz as you admit does not mention ahavas chinam. The OP did not ask if ahava is the cure for sinaas chinam, he asked for the  earliest source for the particular phrase ahavas chinam. Remember  כשם  שקבלתי שכר על הדרישה, כך אני מקבל שכר על הפרישה. There is alot of sources you checked into here which just dont belong.

Comment: @user6591 The Darash Moshe I referenced came before R'Kook by several decades, and he used the concept of ahavas chinam (albeit in a slightly longer linguistic form). I have edited out the drasha that referenced rav kook, I had forgotten it was still in there and originally mistook it for a reference to something else.

Comment: Then you can erase many paragraphs. Also, perhaps instead of linking title pages to prove dates, perhaps link the actual quotes to prove those. At this point, I'm not willing to trust your sources at face value being that the few I was able to check don't pan out.

Comment: @user6591 Not entirely sure I agree with your assessment. I've traced the lineage of Sinas Chinam (Talmud) and Ahavas Chinam (1838 - Matei Moshe) as they developed colloquially and merged in the early 1900's with the Darash Moshe. It's all relevant to the question of "what are the earliest sources for this expression" - The Pele Yoetz starts the chain, and the Darash Moshe/Rav Kook/Imrei Fi end it.

Comment: Was there any doubt when the Chachamim told us about sinaas chinam what we were supposed to correct? I don't really know why anyone who ever mentioned the word sinaas chinam made it into this answer about ahavas chinam. It's very misleading.

Comment: @user6591 On the contrary, earlier answers suggested everything from removing the trait of economic jealousy (Alshich) to renewed commitment to Hashem, to other things entirely. The idea of loving every Jew regardless is pretty modern - they saw no problem hating the irreligious or those whose views diverged significantly from their own. Labeling Ahavah as the solution to the problem of Sinas Chinam is only intuitive to your modern sensibilities.